# Iterate over enums which implement a custom trait

Tags: rust, enums, iterator, traits

I got a problem with Rust, I want to iterate over a vector of severals enum which implement a custom traits.

My custom trait:

```
pub trait PieceFeature
    {
        fn acronym(&self) -> &str;
        fn name(&self) -> &str;
        fn color(&self) -> ConsoleColor;
        fn to_vec_box() -> Vec<Box<Self>> where Self: Sized;
    }
```

I got two enums, the first is Color which implement PieceFeature trait and Display trait :

```
#[derive(Debug, Clone, PartialEq, IntoEnumIterator)]
    pub enum Color {
        White,
        Dark,
    }

    impl PieceFeature for Color {
        fn acronym(&self) -> &str {
            match self {
                Self::White => "W",
                Self::Dark => "D",
            }
        }

        fn name(&self) -> &str {
            match self {
                Self::White => "White",
                Self::Dark => "Dark"
            }
        }

        fn color(&self) -> ConsoleColor {
            ConsoleColor::Blue
        }

        fn to_vec_box() -> Vec<Box<Color>> {
            vec![Box::new(Color::White), Box::new(Color::Dark)]
        }        
    }
    impl Display for Color {
        fn fmt(&self, f: &mut std::fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> std::fmt::Result {
            write!(f, "{}", self.color().paint(self.acronym()))
        }
    }
```

And I got a second (Height) which do exactly the same (I don't write the implementation, but it's exactly as previous)

```
 #[derive(Debug, Clone, PartialEq, IntoEnumIterator)]
    pub enum Height {
        Small,
        Tall,
    }
```

Now I want to dynamically loop over my enum to display a legend in my console application.
I tried severals things but it doesn't work as I want.
Here is my newbie code which work :

```
let pieces_feature: Vec<Box<dyn PieceFeature>> = vec![
            Box::new(Color::Dark),
            Box::new(Color::White),
            Box::new(Height::Small),
            Box::new(Height::Tall),
        ];`
         // some code ...
         //Draw legend
         for (i, e) in pieces_feature.into_iter().enumerate() {
            legend = format!("{} \t {}: {}", legend, e.color().paint(e.acronym()), e.name());
        }
        //....
```

My code works, but I'm not happy to not dynamically build my "pieces_feature" vector.
As you can see, I tried to implement a custom function "to_vec_box()" but I got a error which says that `Vec<Box<Self>>` is not the same as `Vec<Box<dyn PieceFeature>>`.
What is the best way to achieve this ?

Comment: Why not change the signature for `to_vec_box` so that it returns `Vec<Box<dyn PieceFeature>>` instead of `Vec<Box<Self>>`?

Comment: Yes it was exactly what I needed, didn't realized I could use ```dyn``` inside my trait

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options, like:

1. Change your types to what you really want in the method itself (notice you would have to change also the trait method signature):

```rust
fn to_vec_box() -> Vec<Box<dyn PieceFeature>> {
    vec![Box::new(Color::White), Box::new(Color::Dark)]
}
```

2. Iterate over them while changing the types on iteration:

```rust
let features = Color::to_vec_box()
    .into_iter()
    .map(|p| p as Box<dyn PieceFeature>)
    .chain(Height::to_vec_box()
        .into_iter()
        .map(|p| p as Box<dyn PieceFeature>)
    );

for feature in features {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works well :)
I didn't realized I could write ```Vec<Box<dyn PieceFeature>> where Self: Sized``` in my own trait, but of course it make sense.
Have a good day !